# Cant get data's length in itemCount

Tags: api, flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

I want to get my API data's length to use in Listview.builder widget. I want to get my data from API which is 'mahalle'. And this data is a list of data. I want to get this data's length to build a list. But I got an error like this:

```
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4546
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: length
The relevant error-causing widget was
    MahalleList
```

And the reference of the error is :

```
@action
  Future<void> fetcMahalle() async {
    // var data =
    //     await httpClient.getData(globals.SELECT_URL).then((mahalle) => mahalle);
    networkService.getMahalle();
  }
```

And I'm getting my data with :

```
Future getMahalle() async {
    BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: globals.PROD_URL,
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      receiveTimeout: 3000,
    );
    Dio dio = new Dio(options);
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${globals.USER_TOKEN}";
    try {
      var response =
          await dio.get(globals.SELECT_URL); //'api/hizlirapor/selects'

      List<MahalleModel> mahalleList = response.data['mahalle']
          .map<MahalleModel>((mahalle) => MahalleModel.fromJson(mahalle))
          .toList();

      return mahalleList;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint("ERRORR!!!!!!!!!!!!! ${e.error.toString()}");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And finally here's the widget I'm trying to use my list data's length :

```
Container _buildBody(
      BuildContext context, ObservableFuture<List<MahalleModel>> future) {
    return Container(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          _buildSearchBar(context),
          RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: mahalleStore.fetcMahalle,
            child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: mahalleList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final mahalle = mahalleList[index];
                  return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: mainColor,
                            width: 3,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            AppIcon.mahalle_raporu,
                            color: mainColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            mahalle.mahalleAdi,
                            style: textStyle,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your all help !

Comment: can you change `Future getMahalle()` to `Future<List<MahalleModel>> getMahalle()` as it will return `Future<dynamic>`which doesnt have  a length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FutureBuilder(
  future:mahalleStore.fetchMahalle,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
//whatever returns from this function, will be avaliable inside snapshot paremeter.
final mahalleList= snapshot.data;
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
  case ConnectionState.waiting:
    {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
  case ConnectionState.done:
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // do what you want here
    }
    return Text("Error occured");

  default:
    //
}});
```

I deleted previous comment , check this one.

Comment: ```
 The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
_FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#74754):
A build function returned null.
The offending widget is:
  FutureBuilder<dynamic>
Build functions must never return null.
To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
"Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
"Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<dynamic>
``` 
I get a new error with your suggestion :/

Comment: but I tried several times for getting data inside of my NetworkService.dart. And I managed to get mahalle list in it.

Comment: no sadly does not. I got another error that say my FutureBuilder returns null. But I managed to print my data inside getMahalle() .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FutureBuilder` because `getMahalle` returns a `Future`.

Comment: I tried using FutureBuilder than I get FutureBuilder<dynamic> Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()" error.

Comment: FutureBuilder has a Builder function that should return a Widget. Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html